# Defining stochastic and deterministic variables with pymc3

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

I am trying to use write my own `stochastic` and `deterministic` variables with **pymc3**, but old published recipe for **pymc2.3** explained how we can parametrize our variables no longer works. For instance I tried to use this `direct` approach and it failed:

```
def x_logp(value, x_l, x_h):
    if ((value>x_h) or (value<x_l)):
        return -np.inf
    else:
        return -np.log(x_h-x_l+1)
def x_rand(x_l,x_h):
    return np.round((x_h-x_l)*np.random.random_sample())+x_l

Xpos=pm.stochastic(logp=x_logp,
                   doc="X position of halo center ",
                   observed=False, 
                   trace=True,
                   name='Xpos',
                   random=x_rand,
                   value=25.32,
                   parents={'x_l':0,'x_h'=500},
                   dtype=float64,
                   plot=True,
                   verbose=0)
```

I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Stochastic' [unknown]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Stochastic'
```

I am wondering how I could define my own priors or likelihood in `pymc3` without for instance, using decorators  and the available `pymc` distributions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to add custom densities:

1. Theano expressions (can use gradient based samplers)

   You can use `DensityDist` for this, e.g.:
   https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/master/pymc/examples/custom_dists.py
2. Blackbox python functions (only non-gradient samplers like Metropolis, or Slice)

   `Theano` has a decorator you can use like this:

```
@theano.compile.ops.as_op(itypes=[t.lscalar, t.dscalar, t.dscalar],otypes=[t.dvector])
def rate(switchpoint,early_mean, late_mean):
    ''' Concatenate Poisson means '''
    out = empty(years)
    out[:switchpoint] = early_mean
    out[switchpoint:] = late_mean
    return out
```

Taken from this example: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/master/pymc/examples/disaster_model_arbitrary_determinisitc.py

Deterministics can either be done directly by combining the random variables, or, if you want them to show up in the trace using e.g. `pm.Determinstic('sum', alpha + beta)`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'm intending to use the Theano decorator approach (see also https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/507) to allow me to use emcee sampler integrated with PyMC3. I've no specific questions yet but can you hint that this is the right path to go down? Cheers, Jon

Comment: Yes, emcee does not require the gradient so the theano decorator might be the path of least resistance.

If you get emcee to work with pymc3, definitely let us know as it might be nice to combine the two.

Comment: Well, I've some success - simply followed the design pattern in [your blogpost](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/twiecki/WhileMyMCMCGentlySamples/blob/master/content/downloads/notebooks/emcee.ipynb) and created a custom lnprob function to update the PyMC3 model and output the logp back into the emcee sampler. Tested close results to PyMC3 and an OLS and ~100x faster than NUTS on my 6500 x 11 dataset!

I suspect to go the other way round and use the emcee sampler from a PyMC3 call would be even faster, but I've dug into the Theano, PyMC3 and emcee code and it's pretty heavy going.